# executebatch() of preparedstatement not returning the number of batches added

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, teiid

I am trying to add batches from a prepared statement for exact to 3000 times, but when `executebatch()` is called, the number of affected rows returned is 2048, and this happens for values add batch call statements greater than 2048. From where is the count 2048 is returned, I am unable to guess. Can someone please help me with this.

Here is my code for this:

```
    while (resultSet.next()) {
        for (int i = 0,j=0; i < noOfColumns && j < noOfColumns; i++) {
        //Setting values here for preparedStatement using setString()
        }
        pstmt.addBatch(); ==> this is called for more than 3000 times
        try {
            if(++count % batchSize == 0){
             updatedCnt=pstmt.executeBatch();  ==> Here batch size is set to 3000 and executebatch returns 2048
             successRowCnt = successRowCnt + updatedCnt.length;

            }
            if (count ==numberofRowsForCloning) {
                isResultMatch = false;
                break;
            }
        } 

    }
```

Comment: The JDBC implementation could possibly be limiting the maximum number of batches. It might also be limited regarding to available memory.

Comment: Your code is still missing the Complete and Verifiable parts of [mcve]

Comment: @Bernard, I have used the java.sql.PreparedStatement and created it from java.sql.Connection, can you please point out where can i look to find the batches' limit?

Comment: @ManojMajumdar executeBatch returns an array. Do you mean 2048 by the length of the returned array? Can u please show the variables declaration please?

Comment: @ManojMajumdar What is the JDBC driver you're using? Some Drivers do have a limitation on batch operations.

Comment: @Bernard, yes 2048 is the length of the returned array and it is adding up with successCount which is initialized to 0 in the beginning . So int successCount = 0 and int updatedCnt[]=null is the initialization.

Comment: @BandiKishore, I am using JDBC driver of Teiid which is database virtualization tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default limit with Teiid [driver](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/TEIID/JDBC+Translators) for batch insert is 2048.

> **From Doc**: 
>   MaxPreparedInsertBatchSize  The max size of a prepared
>   insert batch.     2048

Try Configuring the property `MaxPreparedInsertBatchSize` to the size you need. 
*Keep in mind, this is usually limited for handling memory.*

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I have been struggling to find the same.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard for giving me the hints toward this.